# Replacing columns with different Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes,namely 'df' and 'df1'

```
df
Out[14]: 
      first country  Rating
0    Robert      US     100
1     Chris     Aus      99
2  Scarlett      US     100

df1
Out[17]: 
        last        Role
0     Downey     IronMan
1  Hemsworth        Thor
2  Johansson  BlackWidow
```

Expected output:

```
      first       last        Role  Rating
0    Robert     Downey     IronMan     100
1     Chris  Hemsworth        Thor      99
2  Scarlett  Johansson  BlackWidow     100
```

I need to drop off the 'country' column and replace with another dataframe(ie. 'df1')

I understand,I can join dataframes and drop 'country' column,but I need columns exactly in this order.

Comment: Have you tried to rearange the columns after you have joined them? Also, what is the output when you join them?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
new_df = df.merge(df1, on='Role').drop('country', axis=1)
new_df = new_df[['first', 'last', 'Role', 'Rating']]
```

Comment: Is there any way I can do it without explicitly giving the column names?

Answer (score 0):

Could you give this a shot?

```py
df1.join(df2, lsuffix='', rsuffix='r_')[["first", "last", "Role", "Rating"]]
```

Output:

```
      first       last        Role  Rating
0    Robert     Downey     IronMan     100
1     Chris  Hemsworth        Thor      99
2  Scarlett  Johansson  BlackWidow     100
```

Comment: Thanks Balaji ! It works.. But is there any way to get it without explicitly mentioning column names?. If I can get by slicing or something, that would be great.. Its hard to mention all the column names for large datasets..

Comment: Can't you get the final list of columns from the column names of the dataframe using `df.columns.tolist()` ?

Answer (score 0):

@Moahmed you can try the below approach:

df2 = pd.concat([df,df1], axis = 1)

df2 = df2[['first','last','Role','Rating']]

df2.head()